# How to let Pandas calculate only last M points for rolling mean?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Say, I have a giant dataframe `df` of `N rows` and N could be 1 billion rows.

If I do

```
df.rolling(window=lookback).mean()
```

I will get the rolling mean (or any rolling operation) for every row (of course rows at beginning may be all N depending on lookback)

No problem for above, but it is very very slow because N is too big.

I only need to do the rolling for the `last M rows` to save time and I only need the results from last M rows. and `M << N`

How can I achieve this? I don't want to writing my own rolling function and is there a way in Pandas or Numpy that I can tell just do some operations for M times and stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can slice then apply the rolling:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.arange(1000)})
M = 10
N = 5

out = df.iloc[-M-N+1:].rolling(N).mean().iloc[N-1:]
```

To be compared with:

```
df.rolling(N).mean().iloc[-M:]
```

example output:

```
       col
990  988.0
991  989.0
992  990.0
993  991.0
994  992.0
995  993.0
996  994.0
997  995.0
998  996.0
999  997.0
```

Comment: Hmm, I guess its not what I mean. Taking your example, say the `window` of rolling_mean is 1000, and min_observation is 1. I only want the last two points to be calculated, how do we do that without calculation on the `iloc[-3], iloc[-4]` etc?